# "Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference" when trying to embed html in webbrowser

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

Trying to embed some html code into a webbrowser gives me [this](https://puu.sh/yIBux/77947f0f48.png) error.
Code I'm trying to embed:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/XXX/XXX.js.php"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-captcha-enable="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How I'm embedding it:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
WebBrowser1.Document.Write(String.Empty)
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources.HTML
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you show what script inside `https://www.example.com/XXX/XXX.js.php`? I suspected your `onload` function doesn't arranged properly, hence your JS is already running before all HTML parts loaded.

Comment: @Jason Phillips  ...also, never initialize a WebBrowser control with `.Navigate("about:blank")`. Use the `HtmlDocument` you get from `WebBrowser.Document.OpenNew(True)` and then `.Write()` to it an html page in HTML5 format (<!DOCTYPE html>) and explicit browser reference (`<head><meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>...</head>`), otherwise you will have IE7 compatibility mode instead of Edge.

Comment: @Jimi error is still there unfortunately

Comment: @Jason Phillips  What I wrote is about the "Presentation" layer. You still need to resolve your coding issues, as suggested in the first comment.

Comment: @Jason Phillips You could also try suppressing the scripting errors  `WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True` to see if the error becomes obvious in the rendering of the page.

Comment: @Jimi I tried that, the content doesn't load at all.

Comment: @Jason Phillips Are you positive the content of the script is working?. Maybe, copy the content of the JS to a local file and reference it in the html page this way.

Comment: Does your .php file contain PHP code?  The web browser control is not designed to read or execute PHP code, only javascript Html and CSS. PHP is a server-side language after all.

Comment: On the same lines as what @Jimi is saying, what do you get when you do `navigator.useragent`?